# Deactivate Buffer Pool SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, buffer, data-warehouse

I have a server for my Datawarehouse (SQL Server 2017 Enterprise), I want to deactivate the buffer pool to some database or tables, is this possible?

Regards

Comment: I suspect you have an XY Problem. What's your actual problem?

Comment: I have in the same server SSAS, SSIS AND SQL Services (- 32GB RAM Server :(  
 ). Sometimes i query a big table by SSIS, i dont want that SQL reserves memory for this tables or its database.  (BTW My Maximun server memory is 16 GB)

Comment: Carlos, If you have you maximum SQL Server memory at 16GB and that's clearly leaving 16GB for the remainder of the systems operations, what is the problem? SQL will manage the memory as needed and recycle when the pages become bottom of the stack so to speak. You are likely to do more damage than good. If you mean buffer pool extensions (as introduced in SQL Server 2014) which is like a page file for SQL then these are disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the extra 16 is for ssas Tabular. I just want 2-3 tables or Db to stop using the bufferpool.